# Counter in Python

Tags: list, python-3.x, counter

Is there a way to collect values in Counter with respect to occurring number?

Example:
Let's say I have a list:

```
list = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd']
```

When I do the Counter:

```
Counterlist = Counter(list)
```

I'll get:

```
Counter({'b': 3, 'a': 3, 'c': 3, 'd': 2})
```

Then I can select let's say *a* and get 3:

```
Counterlist['a'] = 3
```

But how I can select the occurring number '3'? 
Something like:

```
Counterlist[3] = ['b', 'a', 'c']
```

Is that possible?

Comment: The `Counter` is made to filter item to count, not the other way around. The easiest way to reverse it is to pass it to a `defaultdict(list)`.

Comment: `[v for v in Counterlist if Counterlist[v] == 3]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the following

```
import collections

my_data = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd']
result = collections.defaultdict(list)
for k, v in collections.Counter(my_data).items():
    result[v].append(k)
```

and then access `result[3]` to obtain the characters with that count.

Comment: Wow, that's rly elegant. Thanks @Simeon Visser!